# QuickSort Algorithm in C Sorting Just Two Numbers

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm new to algorithms so I'm trying to understand every possible situtation. Last thing I did was to work with QuickSort algorithm sorting integers with a single pivot. My question is: What happens when I have to sort an array with only two integers? For example the `arr[2]={4,2}` . I know that the algorithm works but I'm not sure about how it makes it happen. I didn't found any animation for just 2 numbers, so please can anyone explain me what happens step by step in this situation?

Thanks a lot!
Also, I'm sorry if its a foolish question but I can't figure it out. Have a nice day guys!

Comment: It works the same way as an array with more elements (assuming the base case is an array with only 1 element).

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Can you please explain it clearly? I use a Pivot, a High and a Low.. When I have only 2 integers what happens with the comparisons to swap elements? Thank you!

Comment: It does the same thing as when you have a larger array. I suggest that you use a debugger to step through your implementation to see what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You perform the sorting with two elements as with any generic list size:

1. Pick a pivot. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort for methods of choosing a pivot. For example pivot is the leftmost element `4`.
2. Partition the array in two based on the pivot:

   - `4 < 4` is false. Right hand list.
   - `2 < 4` is true. Left hand list.
3. Sort both lists:

   - Left hand list `{2}` is sorted already
   - Right hand list `{4}` is sorted already
4. Result is *left hand list* plus *right hand list*: `{2, 4}`

Comment: Helped a lot! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on your base case. In many academic implementations, the base cases are an empty array or an array with one element. This means that an array with two elements is treated the same way an array with 1000 elements: pick a pivot, divide the array into two subarrays, then make a recursive call on the two subarrays.

Alternatively, you can treat an array of 2 elements as a base case and sort it directly.

Comment: Can you please make a simple animation for me? A simple sketch of step by step execution with 2 elements? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @KiriakosIoannidis I don't have the time to do that. I suggest you either add print statements to your code or use a debugger to step through it to see what it is doing.

Comment: Ok then no problem, i'll give myself one more try! Thank you for your time!! Happy New Year!!